# TouchableHighlight and TouchableOpacity affect layout on Android

Tags: react-native

I noticed that replacing `TouchableWithoutFeedback` with `TouchableHighlight` or `TouchableOpacity` can cause differences in layout. Is this expected?

Example:

```
<TouchableWithoutFeedback onPress={this.onClick}>
  <View style={styles.row_container}>
    <Text style={styles.row_text}>
      {'I count the number of taps: ' + this.state.clicks}
    </Text>
  </View>
</TouchableWithoutFeedback>
```

With `TouchableWithoutFeedback`:

[image: TouchableWithoutFeedback]

Replacing it with `TouchableOpacity`:

[image: TouchableHighlight]

The styles are:

```
row_container: {
  backgroundColor: 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1)',
  flex: 1,
  height: 100,
  borderColor: '#333333',
  borderWidth: 1,
  borderRadius: 5,
  padding: 5,
},
row_text: {
  flex: 1,
  fontSize: 18,
  alignSelf: 'center',
},
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The solution is not to introduce the wrapper view. Simply set the style directly on `TouchableHighlight` or `TouchableOpacity`:

```
<TouchableOpacity onPress={this.onClick} style={styles.row_container}>
  <Text style={styles.row_text}>
    {'I count the number of taps: ' + this.state.clicks}
  </Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

Comment: Worked perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

To answer the question "is this expected," according to the docs, yes.

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/touchableopacity

"Opacity is controlled by wrapping the children in an Animated.View, which is added to the view hierarchy. Be aware that this can affect layout."

Answer (score 0):

```
<TouchableOpacity style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',backgroundColor:'black',margin:2}}>
   <Image style={{width:30,height:30,marginBottom:3}} source={require('../images/movies_white.png')} />
   <Text style={{color:'#fff'}}>Lịch Sử</Text>
</TouchableOpacity>
```

instead of

```
<View style={{flex:1,justifyContent:'center',alignItems:'center',backgroundColor:'black',margin:2}}>
   <Image style={{width:30,height:30,marginBottom:3}} source={require('../images/movies_white.png')} />
    <Text style={{color:'#fff'}}>Lịch Sử</Text>
</View>
```

Answer (score -1):

style on TouchableOpacsity instead of View

Comment: Could you please add more details to make this answer better?